# Retrieve Data from Repeater item

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, repeater

I have the following Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptLeaveRequests" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table id="tableItem" runat="server">
        <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblHours" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Hours") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 200px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPeriod" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AMorPM") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 200px; font-size:10px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="50px">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtVerified" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Am I trying to loop through each item, find one where the radio button is checked. If a radio button is checked i want to then check its value (Accept or Reject) and retrieve the data (Eval Date,Hours etc) and send it to another method to add to the database.
Can you please help me out, code so far:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptLeaveRequests.Items)
            {
            }
}
```

Comment: this is very simple example to understand repeater : http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/repeater-control-example-in-aspnet.html

Comment: You use `<asp:RadioButtonList>` , but in your code behind , you cast as `RadioButton` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `<asp:RadioButtonList>` , but in your code behind , you cast as `RadioButton` .
 Try likes this ,

```
           foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptLeaveRequests.Items)
           { 
                var rdbList = item.FindControl("rbtVerified") as RadioButtonList;
                switch(rdbList.SelectedValue)
                     {
                      case "1":
                        //Accept
                      break;
                      case "2":
                       //Reject
                      break;
                     }
           }
```

Comment: Can you please check updated? When I try to retrieve the data with for example Convert.ToString((Label)item.FindControl("Date")) it returns an empty string

Comment: `FindControl("Date"))` ? I don't see any control with name `Date` . Do you mean `lblDate` ? Turn your name likes `Convert.ToString((Label)item.FindControl("lblDate"))`